# How to edit data in a column in a DataFrame in Pandas using replace method

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to replace few values in the 'Country' Column using DataFrame.replace() method like below. But it's not working. I tried few other ways too, but no luck. Can anyone help me to fix this?

```
energy = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\New folder\Launchcode\coursera dataScience\course1 week3\Energy Indicators.xls')[16:243]
energy = energy.drop(['Unnamed: 0','Unnamed: 1'], axis = 1).rename(columns={'Environmental Indicators: Energy': 'Country', 'Unnamed: 3': 'Energy Supply', 'Unnamed: 4': 'Energy Supply per Capita', 'Unnamed: 5': '% Renewable'})
energy.replace({"Republic of Korea": "South Korea", "United States of America": "United States", "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland": "United Kingdom", "China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region": "Hong Kong"}, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to specify the column name.

```
energy.Country.replace({...})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `map` method

```
country_map = {
               "Republic of Korea": "South Korea",
               "United States of America": "United States", 
               "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland": "United Kingdom", 
               "China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region": "Hong Kong"
    }
energy[column_name] = energy[column_name].map(country_map)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! When I tried it, it made all the values in 'Country' column NaN

Comment: @Rashida Make sure the `keys` in the `country_map` are the same as the values in the `energy[column]`. Map returns NaN when it couldn't match the keys with the column values.